# ASP.NET 2.0 VS2005 MasterPage doesn't always show an image

Tags: asp.net, image, forms-authentication, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET application that uses a MasterPage.  In the MasterPage I have an image.  This displays well on the development environment and on the default page that inherits it.  But now I have set the website to prompt for a login using Form Authentication.  The Login page also inherits MasterPage but it can't seem to find the image.  Both aspx files (default and login) are in the same directory as the MasterPage.  There is only one image placed in the Images folder.  Has anyone seen this before?  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: Is this occurring in the same dev environment where the default page is displaying the image as desired?  Have you checked the DOM to see if there is some css class(es) or javascript applying styles that hide it on the login page?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same dev environment.  This is a very simple MasterPage that has a table for layout and one content area.  The login inherits the masterpage and uses a Login component to log into the website.  I don't think there is any javascript interfering at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following to allow all users (even unauthenticated users) to access files in the images folder.

```
<location path="images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: That did it.  I guess in a upside down and backwards viewpoint it kind of makes sense.  ;-)